# why dagger is not recommended in Google Architecture Components?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am going to start a new Android app of medium size.

finding a boilerplate code and decided to use Architecture Components recommended by Google.

I went to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower and spend some time inside the architecture. I found dagger which is used the last project, is no more use in Architecture Components.

I don't know why? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In the Readme you can read this:

> A note on dependency injection - while many projects (such as Plaid) use Dagger 2 for DI, there are no plans to incorporate DI into Sunflower. This allows developers unfamiliar with dependency injection to better understand Sunflower's code without having to learn DI.